# Select max value rows from table column

Tags: select, max

my table look like this..

```
id name count
-- ---- -----
1 Mike 0
2 Duke 2
3 Smith 1
4 Dave 6
5 Rich 3
6 Rozie 8
7 Romeo 0
8 Khan 1
----------------------
```

I want to select rows with max(count) limit 5 (TOP 5 Names with maximum count)

that would look sumthing like...

```
id name count
-- ---- -----
6 Rozie 8
4 Dave 6
5 Rich 3
2 Duke 2
3 Smith 1
```

please help,,

thanks

Comment: **WHAT** database system are you using?? Some things are dependent on the product used....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how:

**MySQL:**

```
SELECT * FROM tableName ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 5
```

**MS SQL:**

```
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM tableName ORDER BY count DESC
```